# PHP Table - How to add different hyperlinks on each row of table which is extracted from database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Okay, my problem is that how can I set different hyperlinks to each row of a table in php?

so far i've done this -->

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "makaut_colleges");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM collegelist");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['College Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['College Address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['College Code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Review']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How can i add different hyperlinks to each row which will be extracted from database? i'm using 'College Code' as primary key.

Comment: and hyperlinks coming from? link based on which column?

Comment: <tr onclick="window.location='<?php echo $row['url']; ?>'">

Comment: `College Name` this cant be your column name here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

Try this for making tr clickable

```
 $dynamic_link = "dynamic.php";
    <tr onclick="document.location = '<?php echo $dynamic_link  ?>'">
        td code---------
    </tr>;
```

where `$dynamic_link` is dynamic based on your requirement 
Thier should be some logic or linking with url either save in table or create some link